# deleting a record using OleDbAdapter

Tags: c#, oledbdataadapter

am a beginner in C#. am trying to create a website

i have a problem to give a delete option. there is no error showing. But the recrd is not getting deleted

please help

protected void delete_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        string uname;
        string pwd;

        uname = txt_user.Text;
        pwd = txt_pass.Text;



        string connetionString = null;
        OleDbConnection connection;
        OleDbDataAdapter oledbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        string sql = null;
        connetionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;dsn=xe;User id=sa;password=password123";
        connection = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);

        sql = "DELETE * FROM Login WHERE username='" + uname + "' and password='" +pwd+ "'";
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            oledbAdapter.DeleteCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
            oledbAdapter.DeleteCommand.CommandText = sql;

            oledbAdapter.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Label4.Text = "deleted";
        }
```

thank you

Comment: you do not need the adapter at all, just use connection and command objects. Also careful that you have SQLInjection issues with this design.

Comment: i have used this connection and command objects with OleDBDataReader.

but while deleting is it possible to use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sql should be

```
"DELETE FROM Login WHERE username='" + uname + "' and password='" +pwd+ "'"
```

Remove * from the SQL.

Comment: can i check for a condition "if the record is absent then print invalid"

Comment: OleDbReader is forward only and it does not provide anything like count to determine if any record is selected or not. But you can use the reader.Read() method to check.

Comment: ya..in the searching option i used reader.Read() in while loop